# C++ How do I fix Exception thrown: write access violation. this was nullptr. on Line 20

Tags: c++, exception

*Create a simple linked list program to create a class list containing

```
class node {
        void *info;
            node *next;
public:
            node (void *v) {info = v; next = 0; }
            void put_next (node *n) {next = n;}
        node *get_next ( ) {return next;}
            void *get_info ( ) {return info;}
};
```

Be able to initially fill the list. Provide functions to insert/append nodes and remove nodes from the linked list. Be able to display the contents of the list.
Write a little driver program with at least 5 values passed in (so that 5 nodes are created) as you insert/append, delete and display data, showing the programs operation.
Output: While displaying the data, make sure you use an informational label–using the terms “insert”, “append”, “remove” and any other term which displays the action. All data that is displayed must be displayed in a way in which the mentor can easily read and understand.*

My code runs but it throws Exception thrown: write access violation. this was nullptr. on Line 20 when I debug it. In the output it also stops at Delete 04 of my list and outputs no further data after line 156. I am not sure how to fix this. I tried to force it to output the new list with another cout statement but that did not work. Any assistance would be appreciated. Entire code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    void* info;
    Node* next;
public:
    Node(void* v) { info = v; next = 0; }
    void put_next(Node* n)
    {
        next = n;
    }
    Node* get_next()
    {
        return next;
    }
    void* get_info()
    {
        return info;
    }
};

class List {
    Node* head;
public:
    List() { head = NULL; };
    void PRINT();
    void APPEND(void* info);
    void DELETE(void* info);
};

void List::PRINT() {

    Node* temp = head;

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Enter Values" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (temp->get_next() == NULL)
    {
        cout << *(int*)temp->get_info();
        cout << " => ";
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << *(int*)temp->get_info();
            cout << " --> ";
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }

        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    }
}

void List::APPEND(void* info) {

    Node* newNode = new Node(info);
    newNode->put_next(NULL);

    Node* temp = head;

    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        while (temp->get_next() != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }

        temp->put_next(newNode);
    }
    else
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
}

void List::DELETE(void* info) {

    Node* temp = head;

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Enter Values" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (temp->get_next() == NULL)
    {
        if ((int*)(temp->get_info()) == info)
        {
            delete temp;
            head = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Node* previous = NULL;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if ((int*)(temp->get_info()) == info) break;
            previous = temp;
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }

        previous->put_next(temp->get_next());

        delete temp;
    }
}

int main()
{

    List list;

    int a = 04;
    int b = 11;
    int c = 12;
    int d = 15;
    int e = 29;
    int* Node1 = &a;
    int* Node2 = &b;
    int* Node3 = &c;
    int* Node4 = &d;
    int* Node5 = &e;

    cout << "Append: 04" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node1);
    cout << "Append: 11" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node2);
    cout << "Append: 12" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node3);
    cout << "Append: 15" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node4);
    cout << "Append: 29" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node5);

    cout << endl << "Print List" << endl;
    list.PRINT();

    cout << endl << "Delete 04" << endl;
    list.DELETE(Node1);
    list.PRINT();
    cout << "Start New List" << endl;
    cout << endl << "Delete 12" << endl;
    list.DELETE(Node3);
    list.PRINT();

    return 0;
}
```

SOLUTION:

```
//Node.h

#pragma once
class Node
{
    void* info;
    Node* next;
public:
    Node(void* v) { info = v; next = 0; }
    void put_next(Node* n)
    {
        next = n;
    }
    Node* get_next()
    {
        return next;
    }
    void* get_info()
    {
        return info;
    }
};

//List.h

#pragma once
#include "Node.h"
#include <iomanip>

class List {
    Node* head;
public:
    List() { head = NULL; };
    void PRINT();
    void APPEND(void* info);
    void DELETE(void* info);
};

//List.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;

void List::PRINT() {

    Node* temp = head;

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Enter Values" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (temp->get_next() == NULL)
    {
        cout << *(int*)temp->get_info();
        cout << " => ";
        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << *(int*)temp->get_info();
            cout << " --> ";
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }

        cout << "Invalid" << endl;
    }
}

void List::APPEND(void* info) {

    Node* newNode = new Node(info);
    newNode->put_next(NULL);

    Node* temp = head;

    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        while (temp->get_next() != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }

        temp->put_next(newNode);
    }
    else
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
}

void List::DELETE(void* info) {

    Node* temp = head;

    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Enter Values" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (temp->get_next() == NULL)
    {
        if ((int*)(temp->get_info()) == info)
        {
            delete temp;
            head = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Node* previous = NULL;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if ((int*)(temp->get_info()) == info) {

                // if node is head then changing the head
                if (temp == head)
                    head = temp->get_next();
                break;
            }
            previous = temp;
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }

        // skip this operation if node is head
        if (temp->get_next() != head)
            previous->put_next(temp->get_next());

        delete temp;
    }
}

//Main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "List.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    List list;

    int a = 04;
    int b = 11;
    int c = 12;
    int d = 15;
    int e = 29;
    int* Node1 = &a;
    int* Node2 = &b;
    int* Node3 = &c;
    int* Node4 = &d;
    int* Node5 = &e;

    cout << "Append: 04" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node1);
    cout << "Append: 11" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node2);
    cout << "Append: 12" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node3);
    cout << "Append: 15" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node4);
    cout << "Append: 29" << endl;
    list.APPEND(Node5);

    cout << endl << "Print List" << endl;
    list.PRINT();

    cout << endl << "Delete 04" << endl;
    list.DELETE(Node1);
    list.PRINT();
    cout << "Start New List" << endl;
    cout << endl << "Delete 12" << endl;
    list.DELETE(Node3);
    list.PRINT();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The best way is to familiarize yourself with a debugger...

Comment: Your `DELETE` function doesn't reset `head` correctly when you remove the first node.

Comment: If you could tell me what to do specifically with the debugger I would appreciate that. I am using Visual Studio 2019. (C++ Console App). This is the first time I have had this problem. How would I go about resetting the head correctly?

Comment: I don't use VS myself, but there are surely good tutorials available. Also, your code seems odd, and is not the idiomatic way to do linked-lists. Take a look at some implementations and understand that, and try imitating that.

Comment: BTW, in C++, rather than using `void *`, use `template`.  The type of the data is the data parameter passed to the template.

Comment: Suppose you're trying to delete the first node of a multi-node list. Take pencil and paper, and step through your `DELETE` function.

Comment: In Visual Studio help or manual, look up the terms "breakpoint", "step" and "step into".  Also look up "Add watch variable".  A complete tutorial is too big for a Stack Overflow comment or post (more like YouTube material).

Comment: The assignment requires that we use the class list provided in the statement which includes void. I have only done one template previous to this so I have a better understanding of how void works.

Answer (score 0):

So whenever you are deleting `first` node, you missed to set the `head` to the `next node of head`.

Commented at the parts which are modified in the `else` statement of `DELETE` function

**Code:**

```cpp
else
    {
        Node* previous = NULL;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if ((int*)(temp->get_info()) == info){ 
             
            // if node is head then changing the head
            if (temp == head)
                head = temp->get_next();
                break;
            }
            previous = temp;
            temp = temp->get_next();
        }
        
        // skip this operation if node is head
        if (temp->get_next() != head)
        previous->put_next(temp->get_next());

        delete temp;
    }
```

Comment: @SeaMist187 If this answers your question, consider accepting it.